# Compile proto file with any.proto import

Tags: macos, dart, protocol-buffers, protoc

Here's my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

package Service;

message Message
{
    google.protobuf.Any data = 1;
}
```

I was able to install the protoc on macos with the include directory placed in /usr/local/include.
When I compile the above proto file using the below command from my project folder:

```
protoc --dart_out=generated -Iprotos protos/JMessage.proto --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=$HOME/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart
```

it generates the files in dart, but doesn't find any reference to import '../google/protobuf/any.pb.dart' as $0;

How do I resolve this dependency?

Comment: Is it solved meanwhile? I suffer the same issue...